# Congratulations, Gerry Myerson! Gerry Hits 100K Reputation!!!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user, celebration

[Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson) has just hit $100,000$ reputation on MSE (and EXACTLY $100,000$ rep as I write too). I just wanted to congratulate him for reaching such a big milestone and to thank him for contributing so much to the community. He certainly deserves all of the rep he has. Let's show some appreciation for **Gerry Myerson**!!!

[image: Gerry Myerson's reputation]

Comment: Congratulations on nailing 100k!

Comment: Really happy that you are here Gerry

Comment: Congrats to the one who answered my very first question and thanks for all your other contributions. Let's bump this post [periodically, or even aperiodically](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11240/congratulations-ross-millikan/13090#comment51363_13090)...

Comment: Happy to be here. Someone must have been in a hurry to get me to 100K --- there were about a dozen upvotes of old answers of mine in a short period. Anyway, my thanks to all, and to stackexchange for having this site.

Comment: You were never in a hurry, but you arrived exactly on schedule!  Congratulations.

Comment: Congratulations, Gerry Myerson!

Comment: Thank you, Mr Myerson, your efforts have helped so many people.

Comment: @JChan Could you please stop bumping threads with trivial edits. Every time you do that you waste much time of others who visit the thread to see what is new, only to find some trivial edit.

Comment: Very happy to see you reach the milestone, Gerry!

Comment: congrats! And please, go on with your activities on this website :-)

Comment: Hi Gerry and congratulations from the other side of the bridge!

Comment: Gerry, $10^5$ congrats!

Comment: Congratulations, Gerry! Your long-standing, persistent, and  consistent presence here at MSE - whether via comments, via answering, activity on meta, (and more) - has inspired many of us (you've certainly inspired me and I suspect quite many others), and has helped this site maintain some degree of stability over time, even as many users have come and gone!

Comment: Dear Gerry, congratulations. You deserve it.

Comment: Once again, `@JChan Could you please stop bumping threads with trivial edits. Every time you do that you waste much time of others who visit the thread to see what is new, only to find some trivial edit.`

Answer (score 7):

**Congratulations,  Gerry Myerson!** What is just so *amazing* about this is that you hit exactly $100,000$ reputation,  and for this I take my hat off to you (though I'm not wearing one)!

Comment: haha yes that takes a real skill:P

Answer (score 2):

Ya! Congrats! this is just the beginning!

Answer (score 2):

Congrats! :D Hope another 100k is on the way :D